# MariaDB SQL syntax error with Output file Concatenation

Tags: mariadb

What am I doing wrong here at line 7? Can't seem to figure this one out. Anyone willing to help? Thanks

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '11:29:08' at line 7

Line 7

> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

```
SET @sql_text = 
               CONCAT (
                    "SELECT price_id, customer, location, tier, channel_segment, product, best_before_date, brand, pack, price, tonnes, date_reported, created_at, week
                    INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Temp/price_data_"
                    , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
                    , ".csv' 
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    FROM price_data_summary
                    WHERE date_reported >=", now()-interval 3 month);

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Comment: Change `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` by `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'`.

Comment: Hey @wchiquito tried that but still gives the error. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Change `WHERE date_reported >=", now()-interval 3 month);` by `WHERE date_reported >= '", now() - interval 3 month, "'");`.